# Use of !important statement in media query file?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm using media queries for the first time for my portfolio website. I
have to use `**!important**` statement when I need to alter, lets say,
padding of a logo for a portrait version and also for a landscape
version. I have an external stylesheet linked to my media query
stylesheet and to over-ride styles from the main stylesheet I have to
use important for my media query in order for it to listen to it.

The `!important` tags are stopping me from re-styling other devices further down the stylesheet because they are needed in order to style my ipad version of my website.

Seems that I can add a style into a query that is new like `display:none`, but if I need to add `padding-left:20px`, I need the `!important` tag to over ride the main stylesheet.

Can you help?

Comment: Need to see code. Generally you can prevent most overriding problems if you keep your selectors balanced *and* you place your external media query stylesheet link *after* the main stylesheet link.

Comment: Might suggest using separate class or id names for those that you do not wish to be overwritten by the !important tag.

Answer (score 2):

As previous answers have stated it's best to avoid using !important except in some very specific and limited situations.

If you find you're using it to override styles it could be a symptom of a couple of different problems. Perhaps you're using a high specificity selector like `#header #logo` in the first rule and trying to override it with a class like .logo in the media query block.

Another cause can be long selectors eg `#header #header-inner .logo-wrap #logo` which is a pretty bad idea too. More on that from Harry Roberts at http://csswizardry.com/2012/05/keep-your-css-selectors-short/

It's hard to know without seeing your code but in general trying to keep selectors short and using a [modular approach to CSS](http://smacss.com/) will help.

Just to add to chipcullen's list of when it can be useful to use !important:

- In HTML emails
- If you need a helper class to override everything eg .valid or .hidden
- To override browser default stylesheets that use it

And as mentioned in print sylesheets and when working with 3rd party code that can't be changed.

(I would disagree that it should be used to override styles injected by JavaScript because there are better ways to achieve the same ends by manipulating class names instead, thus sidestepping the problem. The classList API makes this very easy and there are polyfills available too.)

Answer (score 0):

As the first commenter said, we need to see some code.

Overall, it sounds like you are running into specificity issues. You really shouldn't need to use `!important` except in three cases:

- Overriding styling applied by JavaScript
- In a print style sheet
- Altering an element that is loaded from an external source, and you can't edit the original styles

When it comes to media queries, and specificity, remember that order matters. If selectors have the same level of specificity, the last one wins. In general, a good approach when constructing a style sheet with media queries is:

1. Global styles that apply in most cases - starting with mobile sizes devices (i.e. "mobile first")
2. Later media queries go 'up' in sizes - larger and larger, and apply style overrides as necessary